# Similarly sized text on different websites looks different on my iPhone

Tags: css, ember.js, responsive-design

I have a simple prototype app up at http://readinglist.samselikoff.com/.

I'm designing the site for mobile-only (it's just a personal project). For some reason, the text is showing up very small when I pull it up on my iPhone 5.

I've made other websites with similarly sized text that shows up much bigger. One possible explanation is that I'm using [Ember.js](http://www.emberjs.com) which wraps DOM elements in script tags.

Does anybody else experience this with my site? How does it look on your mobile? For example, the `<h1>` tag is 48px. Other sites I've inspected that use similar font sizes (at a device-width of <480px) look much bigger on my iPhone. Could it be Ember, or am I missing something?

**Update:** here are some screens. The first two are from Chrome on my desktop, width of 480px:

[image]

These are from my iPhone:

[image]

The text of both headings is 50px (when I inspect from Chrome desktop). Why does "Reading List" become so small on my iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default mobile browsers pretend to be desktop browsers by rendering at a larger viewport size. The specific sizes vary depending on your platform. You need to override this behaviour by adding a `viewport` meta tag to your html.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
```

Here's a good [intro](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/an-introduction-to-meta-viewport-and-viewport/) to using viewports.

Comment: Wonderful, brilliant, marvelous! I knew I was missing something. This was really bugging me, so thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Script tags are ignored by correct browser implementation.  It showed up normal in Chrome and the default android browser, I don't have an Iphone to test it on though.  Is the system text size mucking with the browser?  You might try switching the system text size around and see if it changes in the browser.

Comment: I still feel like I'm missing something. Check out [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) on your mobile. The main header is 50px. Now go back to my site - it's also 50px. Isn't it much smaller?

Comment: 50px on your phone vs 50px on a laptop are not equal.  Pixel per inch ratios are different per device.  (Think about a 720p 50" tv vs 1080p 50" tv).  That being said, an iphone is 326 ppi, compared to a normal mac book pro 13" which is 113 ppi.  So those 50 pixels on an iphone 5 is only 1/6" whereas on that macbook it's 1/2".

Comment: I just saw your update.  Feel free to ignore my previous comment if it doesn't apply.